# Why does man not find entries?

Tags: centos, man

```
> man ls
No manual entry for ls

> man tar
No manual entry for tar
```

Every command cannot be found, except Git. I installed git a while ago and had trouble getting the git man to show up. I forget what I did and, now git can be found and every else cannot be found. **I have tried yum update, install for man and man-pages.** I think the problem is just assigning the correct path for man to find the pages.  No sure how to do that.
I'm using CentOS 7.

Some info...

```
> man -w
/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man

> man -w git
/usr/local/share/man/man3/Git.3pm
```

Comment: May need to change MANPATH, as suggested here... https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/%27man%27-command-does-not-work-no-manual-entry-for-ls-4175607007/

Comment: @DavidYockey I have tried that and has not worked.

Comment: @sourcejedi sorry about the mistake. The it has the e.

Comment: What is the output of `command man`? Do you still have `/usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz`?  If so, what happens if you run `man -l /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz`?

Comment: lol they work with sudo... hmm

Comment: lol. sounds like you might have broken some permissions with a wild `chmod -R`.

Comment: @sourcejedi I think its a permission issue. commands work with sudo.

Comment: @sourcejedi yes, not sure why git works with out sudo, and others need it. Will deal with the issue as a permission problem. Thanks!